# Is there a per-IP-address limit on the Twitter streaming API?

Tags: twitter

I understand that the Twitter streaming API only allows for a single connection per user account on Twitter. I was wondering if multiple streaming connections from the same IP address are allowed, if each connection has credentials from a different user account? For example, in a scenario where a single server may process tweets for multiple users. Specifically, I am curious about the filtered public streams endpoint.

I have read the following, and cannot locate an answer:
[Twitter Streaming API limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962677/twitter-streaming-api-limits)
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public

Thank you, -Matt

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I have three different Twitter API streams in a Node-RED application running on the same IP with no problem. Whenever I make changes or redeploy I do get rate limit errors for the first minute or so, but they go away and do not appear again.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Streaming API supports up to two connections on a single IP. Any more than that will result in the oldest stream being disconnected. The developer agreement and policy states that you should not use multiple application keys and/or IP addresses to circumvent this limitation.

Note that it is on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/myf7rKwV/twitter-developer-platform-roadmap) for the standard filter and sample streams to eventually be updated with new versions, but it is not yet clear if they will carry the same connection limitations.

Comment: Is the two connection limit per-IP documented anywhere? Not looking to use multiple application keys or IP addresses, was more interested if a SaaS project can use multiple users' streaming API keys from the same IP address to process different tweets for different users.

Comment: There's some information about connections and limits on this page. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting

I believe different user credentials should be fine.

Comment: what if the machines are behind a WAN inside a LAN? would that be considered as single IP?

Comment: Most likely yes