# How many keywords is too many to put in a Tweepy filter while streaming live data

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have code similar to the code below and was wondering how many keywords I could put in the filter without denigrating performance. I realize the answer would depend on several factors affecting the computers performance such as processor speed, connection speed and the likes from the sending computer but how many will Twitter accept? Also is there a rule of thumb to determine how many from the sending computer? I would like around 3000. Is that too many?

```
import sys
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_key = ''
access_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):     
    def on_status(self, status):        
        x = str(status) 
        words = x.split()        
        for word in words:
            screen_name = status.user.screen_name
            user_id = status.user.id
            tweet = status.text                      
            print word, "  |  ", screen_name,"  |  ", user_id 
            print tweet               

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['filter1', 'filter2'])
```

Comment: @agtoever The page you referred to discusses REST API limits not Streaming API

Comment: There is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962677/twitter-streaming-api-limits)about Twitter's streaming api limits...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Streaming API limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962677/twitter-streaming-api-limits)

Comment: @agtoever The question was never really about limits but keyword filters

Comment: I tried to pass about 500 keywords into a Tweepy filter and it returned a 403 error. Has anybody found a solution to this problem?